# How to create text boxes dynamically in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to design a simple android  application.That prompt user to enter number of numbers you want.Then it should create text boxes dynamically according to user requirements.can any one give me the code.Thanks in advance

Comment: No, we can't do your work for you. Attempt it yourself, then come back if you have a specific problem that you need help with. SO is NOT a free code writing service.

Comment: Is there any `TextBox` in android ?

Comment: Possibly he comes from .NET... I guess he means `EditText`

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi haha Maybe, Correct guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are asking will be closed soon because of off-topic but I will give you little tips about adding the `TextView` OR `EditText`, If you want to add `TextView` in `number` of times then do like this

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
  TextView tv=new TextView(this);
  tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
  tv.setText("TextView "+i);
  this.myLayout.addView(tv); //Where mLayout is your Parent Layout
 }
```